# Aligning collection view cells to fit exactly 3 per row

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I am trying to make a collection view of images, so that there are 3 per row, with no spacing in between.

My collection view data sources are:

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return posts.count
}
```

and this is how it's set up in my storyboard (imageView width is 125, a third of the 375 screen width):

[image]

However when I run the app and add some photos, it looks like this:

[image]

How can I fix this so that I see 3 images per row? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you really _need_ a collection view here? It's so easy just to _make_ a grid of image views such as you describe, in code. If you don't need any other collection view features, why bother with a collection view for something so basic?

Comment: I guess that would be another way to do it, I'll keep it in mind for another project. The issue is solved now so I might as well keep it as a collection view - would there be any advantage to using your approach instead, or is it just easier to implement initially?

Comment: The "advantage" would only have been that you clearly didn't know how to make a collection view with the desired structure. Stay with it if the problem is solved, by all means!

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You have to implement the

> UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

for the spacing stuff.

Set the size of the collectionViewCells like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let yourWidth = collectionView.bounds.width/3.0
    let yourHeight = yourWidth

    return CGSize(width: yourWidth, height: yourHeight)
}
```

You can also add these functions to get your spacing of the collectionViewCells correct:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets.zero
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
```

Answer (score 37):

**Swift - Version 4.2**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let noOfCellsInRow = 3

    let flowLayout = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout

    let totalSpace = flowLayout.sectionInset.left
        + flowLayout.sectionInset.right
        + (flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing * CGFloat(noOfCellsInRow - 1))

    let size = Int((collectionView.bounds.width - totalSpace) / CGFloat(noOfCellsInRow))

    return CGSize(width: size, height: size) 
}
```

Comment: this works perfectly, I use this with 4 cells in row just changing the noOfCellsInRow value and shows proportional and aligned correctly.

Answer (score 8):

**1-** You have to conform to [UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout)

**2-** You should implement [collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout/1617708-collectionview) method, as follows:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    let scaleFactor = (screenWidth / 3) - 6

    return CGSize(width: scaleFactor, height: scaleFactor)
}
```

Assuming that the minimum spaces are 8 -for example-,

[image]

the output should be three items for each row, square sized.

Remark: If you want to set the spaces between the cells to be zero, then `scaleFactor` should be:

```
let scaleFactor = (screenWidth / 3)
```

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 6):

you can use this

This code is somehow written that you can change section inset or minimumInteritemSpacing and this calculate and resize with this parameters

you can use this code or download project from [Github](https://github.com/sadeghgoo/collectionViewFlowLayout)

```swift
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {


        let flowLayout = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout

        let numberofItem: CGFloat = 3

        let collectionViewWidth = self.collectionView.bounds.width

        let extraSpace = (numberofItem - 1) * flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing

        let inset = flowLayout.sectionInset.right + flowLayout.sectionInset.left

        let width = Int((collectionViewWidth - extraSpace - inset) / numberofItem)

        print(width)

        return CGSize(width: width, height: width)
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to implement the

**UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout**
for the spacing stuff.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return  10
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "UpperCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! UpperCollectionViewCell
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    return CGSize(width: (self.collectionView.frame.width/3.0) - 5 , height: (self.collectionView.frame.height/4.0))
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return  2
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return  2
}
```

Comment: it works after putting `Estimate size` to `none` to show the size inspector section