# Remove space between the cells of UICollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, rx-swift

I have `UICollectionViewCell`s that have only one `UIImageView`. I am using `RxSwift` for the project. The `delegate` is set in the `Main.storyboard`, and the `datasource` is set by the `RxSwift`. I need to remove the spaces between the cells, but having trouble with that. The methods from this thread are not working:

[Aligning collection view cells to fit exactly 3 per row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42698678/aligning-collection-view-cells-to-fit-exactly-3-per-row)

I tried both answers but nothing happens.

Here is the `UIViewCollectionController`s' code:

```
let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Register cell classes
    //self.collectionView!.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    collectionView?.dataSource = nil
    setupCellConfiguration()
}

private func setupCellConfiguration() {
    //1
    immuneCells
        .bind(to: self.collectionView!
            .rx //2
            .items(cellIdentifier: CellTypeCollectionViewCell.Identifier,
                   cellType: CellTypeCollectionViewCell.self)) { // 3
                    row, cellType, cell in
                    cell.configureWithCellType(cellType: cellType) //4
        }
        .disposed(by: disposeBag) //5
}

override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}


override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
    let num = CellType.immune.count
    return num
}

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    let scaleFactor = (screenWidth / 3) - 6

    return CGSize(width: scaleFactor, height: scaleFactor)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets.zero
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

> Update

I tried setting up equal width and height, top, left constraints of `UIImageView` but it did not help.

This is how it looks:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible that there is 0 space between your cells, but your images don't fill your cells? How are the cells laid out?

Comment: I added constraints, but it did not help either.

Comment: Did you set the imageView's contentMode to scaleToFill?

Comment: Yes, it is set in the storyboard

Comment: You should be using the bounds of the collectionView: `let screenWidth = collectionView.bounds.width`.  Could you add a `print(screenWidth);print(scaleFactor)` to your `sizeForItemAt` function?

Comment: Nothing is printed. Maybe smth is wrong with the referencing outlets? Delegate of the `UICollectionView` is set to its `UICollectionViewController`

Comment: Try adding `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` to your `UICollectionView`'s class definition line.  Something like: `class MyCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {`

Comment: It works! Awesome!

Comment: Great! I'll make that an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, it is apparent that your `FlowLayout` methods are not being called.

Add `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` to your `UICollectionView`'s `class` definition line.

Something like:

```
class MyCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
```

That will tell iOS that your `class` implements that protocol and supports the layout methods so that it knows to call them.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
```

Comment: It is writing me that `UICollectionView` has no member `minimumLineSpacing`

Comment: Probably `flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0` `flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0` is what he meant

Answer (score 1):

You should use `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.
Below is sample code:

```
var flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
let numberOfItemsPerRow = 3
let itemSpacing = 5.0
let lineSpacing = 5.0

let width = ((self.collectionView?.width)! - itemSpacing*(numberOfItemsPerRow+1)) / numberOfItemsPerRow
flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: width)
flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = itemSpacing
flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(lineSpacing, lineSpacing, lineSpacing, lineSpacing)
self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout = flowLayout
```