# UICollectionViewCell not aligning properly when multiple cells added

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionViewCell` in a `UICollectionView` configured with a `UIImage` and `UILabel`. I am trying to add multiple rows of the cell and have defined it to have 3 cells per row. However, the second cell that renders is aligned on the right side of the view and it just starts goes to the next row instead.

My Storyboard:

[image: my storyboard]

When I add multiple cells:

[image: when I add multiple cells]

I have tried setting up custom layout sizing but I am still running into the same issue where the second cell is right aligned which messes up the entire layout.

```
        let collectionViewWidth = collectionView.frame.width
        let itemWidth = (collectionViewWidth-leftAndRightPaddings)/numberOfItemsPerRow
        let itemHeight = (8*itemWidth)/6

        let layout = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
```

Not sure where I am going wrong here.

Comment: Refer this link it might Help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42698815/10790218

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this one solved. The issue was the spacing between the cells which was messing up the alignment. Adding these two lines did the trick:

```
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
```